# Others UIImageView NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsmutablearray

I have 5 pictures and i want to add to array

code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

UIImageView *pic;
NSMutableArray *picArray;

@interface ViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *picArray;

@end


@implementation ViewController
@synthesize picArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    picArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 75)];
    pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 110);
    [picArray addObject:pic];

    pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 120);
    [picArray addObject:pic];

    pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 130);
    [picArray addObject:pic];

    pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4.png"];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 140);
    [picArray addObject:pic]; 

    pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic5.png"];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 150);
    [picArray addObject:pic]; 


    pic = [picArray objectAtIndex:0];

    pic.center = CGPointMake(200, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:pic];


}
```

When I build and run this code I see only last picture of my array only pic5.png
regardless of the index

When I used NSString in my array all ok, but in I used images no(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new `UIImageView` each time. Currently you just create a single `UIImageView`, and change its image five times. You've added five versions of the same image view object to your array.

Something like this:

```
pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 75)];
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 110);
[picArray addObject:pic];

// Note how a new image is created here
pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 75)
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 120);
[picArray addObject:pic];

// ...etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes last image only displayed here because you are just changing the images in imageview .
take different imageview's with different frames and add it to view.

for adding images in your view you can take one for loop and add images based on your frames.

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, i*75, 50, 75)
    pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic%d.png",i];
    pic.center = CGPointMake(100, 120);
    [self.view addObject:pic];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

everytime you add a new pic you have to reinitialize UIImageView;

```
  pic = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 75)
```

add that in front of

```
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic5.png"];
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic4.png"];
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic3.png"];
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic2.png"];
pic.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic1.png"];
```

in your code and you should be kosher.